# Merge columns on two left joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables as shown:

```
Video
+----+--------+-----------+
| id |  name  | videoSize |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | video1 | 1MB       |
|  2 | video2 | 2MB       |
|  3 | video3 | 3MB       |
+----+--------+-----------+

Survey
+----+---------+-----------+
| id |  name   | questions |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 | survey1 |         1 |
|  2 | survey2 |         2 |
|  3 | survey3 |         3 |
+----+---------+-----------+

Sequence
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
| id | videoId | surveyId  | sequence |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | null    | 1         |        1 |
|  2 | 2       | null      |        2 |
|  3 | null    | 3         |        3 |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+
```

I would like to query Sequence and join on both of video and survey tables and merge common columns without specifying the column names (in this case `name`) like this:

```
Query Result:
+----+---------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| id | videoId | surveyId  | sequence |  name   | videoSize | questions |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | null    | 1         |        1 | survey1 | null      | 1         |
|  2 | 2       | null      |        2 | video2  | 2MB       | null      |
|  3 | null    | 3         |        3 | survey3 | null      | 3         |
+----+---------+-----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Is this possible?

BTW the below sql doesn't work as it doesn't merge on the `name` field:

```
SELECT * FROM "Sequence"
LEFT JOIN "Survey" ON "Survey"."id" = "Sequence"."surveyId"
LEFT JOIN "Video" ON "Video"."id" = "Sequence"."videoId"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will show what you want:

```
select
  s.*,
  coalesce(y.name, v.name) as name, -- picks the right column
  v.videoSize,
  y.questions
from sequence s
left join survey y on y.id = s.surveyId
left join video v on v.id = s.videoId
```

However, the SQL standard requires you to name the columns you want. The only exception being `*` as shown above.

Comment: thanks for the response! unfortunately im hoping to not have to name the fields themselves as it can get quite length. so im assuming there's no way then

Comment: Being an ORM developer myself I've always thought about this shortcoming of SQL. According to the standard you need to name the columns one by one, and that can become quite lengthy for big tables. I have thought about filters that could produce "the columns not mentioned before", or "the columns that are not LOBs", or "the columns whose name matches a regex, a type and/or length", etc. So far, however, there's nothing like, and I'm not sure it makes sense either. Just my opinion.